# Show that there is no natural number $n$ such that $3^7$ is the largest power of $3$ dividing $n!$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, factorial, prime-factorization

> Show that there is no natural number $n$ such that $7$ is the largest power $a$ of $3$ for which $3^a$ divides $n!$

After doing some research, I could not understand how to start or what to do to demonstrate this.

We have $$E_3(n!)\neq7\;\;\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\\\left[\frac{n}{3} \right]+\left[\frac{n}{3^2} \right]+\left[\frac{n}{3^3} \right]+\dots\neq7$$I do not know where from, or what to do to solve it.

Comment: Do you mean "Show that there is no natural number such that 7 is the largest power $a$ of 3 for which $3^a$ is divisible by $n!$?

Comment: @amWhy Yes, perhaps it was not clear as use a translator, I do not speak / write / understand English.

Comment: You did fine. Really (and I wouldn't have guessed you were a non-native speaker). I just wanted to make sure the reference to "power of 3" was 7 here.

Comment: @amWhy with respect, hasn't your latest edit made the question (or at least both answers) incorrect?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For $n=15,\left[\frac{15}{3} \right]+\left[\frac{15}{3^2} \right]+\left[\frac{15}{3^3} \right]+\;...=6$
for $n=18$ (the next multiple of $3$)  $\left[\frac{18}{3} \right]+\left[\frac{18}{3^2} \right]+\left[\frac{18}{3^3} \right]+\;...=8$
If $n\geq 18$ then $\left[\frac{n}{3} \right]+\left[\frac{n}{3^2} \right]+\left[\frac{n}{3^3} \right]+\;...\geq 8$
So there is no possibility for $7$

Comment: I understand very well liked, thank you!!

Comment: @marcelolpjunior keep searching enjoy the journey!

Answer (score 5):

Hint:  What is the smallest value $n_1$ such that $3^7\mid (n_1)!$?  What is the largest value $n_0$ such that $3^7\nmid (n_0)!$?  What is the largest exponent $k$ such that $3^k\mid (n_1)!$?

Comment: I'm Sorry, but I do not know.

Comment: For $n!$, we have $1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4\cdot 5\cdot 6\cdots 9\cdots 12\cdots n$, so we only need to count up to $7$ powers of $3$ among these.  If $n=15$, then we have $3,6,9,12,15$ which is $6$ powers of $3$.  What happens if $n\gt 17$?

Comment: @abissu $$E_3(n!)>7?$$

Comment: Note that (as mentioned in the other answer), $$E_3(18!)=\left[\frac{18}{3} \right]+\left[\frac{18}{3^2} \right]+\left[\frac{18}{3^3} \right]+\dots=8,$$ while $$E_3(17!)=\left[\frac{17}{3} \right]+\left[\frac{17}{3^2} \right]+\left[\frac{17}{3^3} \right]+\dots=6,$$ to use your notation.  My answer hints at writing out all the numbers explicitly and counting each factor individually.  Since $n!$ is an incremental function, i.e., $(n+1)!=(n+1)\cdot n!$, this is a very easy process to go through.

Comment: Got it, thanks ... $$: D$$